# Как обеспечить доступ JavaFX-контроллерам к primaryStage с помощью Spring без жесткого связывания?

Tags: java, spring, javafx

На момент написания данного вопроса я нахожусь в самом начале понимания концепции инъекции зависимости, и всё, что умею делать с `ApplicationContext` из Spring - это объявлять бины в xml-файле, а также создавать интерфейсы, их реализации, а также получать их, например:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {

  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

  IFilesManager FilesManager = (dev.example.FilesManager.FilesManager) applicationContext.getBean("FilesManager");
  FilesManager.initializeUserFiles();
}
```

Этих знаний недостаточно, чтобы справиться с такой задачей: нужно передать `primaryStage` (экземпляр `javafx.stage.Stage`) в контроллер. Стандартно, это делается через жесткое связывание главного класса приложения и контроллера.

В главном классе приложения:

```java
// Даём контроллеру доступ к главному приложению.
PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setMainApp(this);
```

В контроллере:

```java
/**
* Вызывается главным приложением, которое даёт на себя ссылку.
* @param mainApp
*/
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
}
```

Стандартно, `primaryState` можно получить от `MainApp` через геттер последнего:

```java
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
  return primaryStage;
}
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли сделать это через `ApplicationContent`? Стандартно, `primaryStage` является полем главного класса приложения, которое инициализируется в методе `start`, который должен быть реализован в наследнике `javafx.application.Application`.

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
  this.primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX test");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен доступ к stage внутри контроллера, то эта задача решается проще. Любой графический контрол, являющийся полем класса и аннотированный `@FXML`, знает в какой stage он находится.

```java
((Stage)myPane.getScene().getWindow())
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Comment: У меня возникла `myPane.getScene()` вернуло `null`. Что это значит?

Comment: Объект `myPane` не был инициализирован.

Comment: Я попробовал вывести в консоль компоновку (у меня это `AnctorPane`) - вывелось `AnchorPane@7574b692`. null возвращает `anchorPane.getScene()`. Если Вас не затруднит, то посмотрите, пожалуйста [проект](https://yadi.sk/d/LxfB_SFsAVGBxw), класс `PersonOverviewController`. Так как проект собирается maven, то mwe будет очень большим и потребуется время, чтобы его из него сделать проект в среде разработки, потому проще так выложить проект.

Comment: Я так понимаю проблема в строчке `dialogStage.initOwner(dialogRootLayout.getScene().getWindow());` Не помню, доводилось ли мне использовать этот метод, но по описанию туда должен передаваться параметр окна из которого происходит вызов, а `dialogRootLayout` это сущность из мира `PersonEditDialogController`. А вот то, что у нее метод getScene() возвращает null это интересно. Видимо это работает только внутри контроллера для полей которые были инжекнуты через @FXML аннотации.  `dialogStage.initOwner(familyNameLabel.getScene().getWindow());` должно сработать, на java11 проверить сам не могу сейчас

Comment: Ваше предположение оказалось абсолютно правильным, у меня действительно всё заработало! Я подправлю Вас ответ, чтобы не отнимать у  Вас ещё больше времени. Спасибо Вам за помощь!